# SQL query to find maximum number of attended events by user given a year

Tags: mysql, sql, sequence, gaps-and-islands

I am having a tough time wrapping my head around this one. Here's what I have:

```
user_id | year
1 | 2015
1 | 2016
1 | 2018
1 | 2019
1 | 2020
2 | 2015
2 | 2016
2 | 2017
2 | 2018
2 | 2019
```

What I need is a result:

```
user_id | count
1 | 3
2 | 5
```

So for each user, I need to know the longest consecutive streaks with no gaps based on year. User 1 had a gap in 2017 so the longest streak is 2018-2020. User 2 had no breaks so their streak is 5 years. I want to make sure any gaps reset the count essentially. I've found a number of solutions for counting dates and such but I can't seem to find one for an increasing integer values that it essentially has to be the very next in sequence not just larger. I'm hoping for a clever MySQL compatible query.

Comment: MySQL what version?

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/

Comment: @CaiusJard - I've been using 5.7 but I'm going to add 8 because I realized this is tougher with 5.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method.  Subtract a sequence number -- which is constant for consecutive values.  Then aggregate and pull out the longest:

```
select t.*
from (select user_id, count(*) as streak_length,
             min(year) as min_year, max(year) as max_year,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by user_id order by year) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
      group by user_id, year - seqnum
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This works! Luckily I'm not dealing with much data nor would it be something I'm relying on performance for. The key though was I needed MySQL 8 because I couldn't partition the data. Appreciate it!